# Inheritance with JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance

I need to transform some "ul" and "li" tags into a JavaScript objects. 
I have succeeded to transform all tags into objects but I don't know how can I apply an inheritance to have the first object which contains the children objects...
I'm using a recursive function in my code :

```
   var getDir = function(child) {
            if(child.getAttribute('id')) {
                var dir = child.getAttribute('id');
                dir = dir.split("/");
                dir.pop();
                dir = dir.join("/");
                return dir;
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        var getName = function(child) {
            if(child.getAttribute('id')) {
                var name = child.getAttribute('id');
                name = name.split("/");
                name = name.pop();
                return name;
            }
        }

        function Recursive(nodes, count)
        {
            if(nodes.childNodes)
            {
                for(let child of nodes.childNodes)
                {

                    if(child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName === "LI")
                    {
                        var content = new Object();
                        content.dir = getDir(child);
                        content.name = getName(child);
                        content.type = child.type;
                        if(child.getAttribute('class') && child.getAttribute('class') === "error") {
                            content.corrupted = true;
                        }

                        console.log(content);
                        console.log("-".repeat(count) + "element: " + child.tagName);  
                    }
                    if(child.childNodes) {
                        Recursive(child, count+1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Recursive(treeModule, 0);
```

treeModule is an HTML content :

```
<ul>
                <li id="myProject" type="folder">myProject
                    <ul>
                        <li id="myProject/css" type="folder">css
                            <ul>
                                <li id="myProject/css/main.css" type="file">main.css</li>
                                <li id="myProject/css/menu.css" type="file">menu.css</li>
                                <li id="myProject/css/user.css" type="file">user.css</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="myProject/fonts" class="empty" type="folder">fonts</li>
                        <li id="myProject/images" type="folder">images
                            <ul>
                                <li id="myProject/images/logo.png" class="error" type="file">logo.png</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="myProject/index.html" type="file">index.html</li>
                        <li id="myProject/js" type="folder">js
                            <ul>
                                <li id="myProject/js/controllers" type="folder">controllers
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/controllers/core" type="folder">core
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="myProject/tempjs/controllerslates/core/menu.js" type="file">menu.js</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/controllers/errors" type="folder">errors
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="myProject/js/controllers/errors/error.js" type="file">error.js</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/controllers/home" type="folder">home
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="myProject/js/controllers/home/homePage.js" type="file">homePage.js</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/controllers/home" type="folder">home
                                            <ul>
                                                <li id="myProject/js/controllers/user/list.js" type="file">list.js</li>
                                                <li id="myProject/js/controllers/user/login.js" type="file">login.js</li>
                                                <li id="myProject/js/controllers/user/profile.js" type="file">profile.js</li>
                                                <li id="myProject/js/controllers/user/subscribe.js" type="file">subscribe.js</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="myProject/js/libs" type="folder">libs
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/libs/handlebars.min.js" type="file">handlebars.min.js</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/libs/jquery.min.js" type="file">jquery.min.js</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/libs/require.min.js" class="error" type="file">require.min.js</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="myProject/js/main.js" type="file">main.js</li>
                                <li id="myProject/js/models" type="folder">models
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/models/menu.js" type="file">menu.js</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/models/user.js" type="file">user.js</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/js/models/users.js" type="file">users.js</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="myProject/ressources" class="empty" type="folder">ressources</li>
                        <li id="myProject/views" type="folder">views
                            <ul>
                                <li id="myProject/templates/core" type="folder">core
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/core/footer.html" type="file">footer.html</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/core/header.html" type="file">header.html</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/core/menu.html" type="file">menu.html</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="myProject/templates/errors" type="folder">errors
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/errors/error401.html" type="file">error401.html</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/errors/error403.html" type="file">error403.html</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/errors/error404.html" class="error" type="file">error404.html</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="myProject/templates/home" type="folder">home
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/home/homePage.html" type="file">homePage.html</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li id="myProject/templates/home" type="folder">home
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/user/list.html" type="file">list.html</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/user/login.html" type="file">login.html</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/user/profile.html" type="file">profile.html</li>
                                        <li id="myProject/templates/user/subscribe.html" type="file">subscribe.html</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

And I would like that the deepest "li" becomes the deepest child in my object like this :

```
{
  "dir": "",
  "name": "folder",
  "type": "folder",
  "children": [
    {
      "dir": "folder",
      "name": "cascading",
      "type": "folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "dir": "folder/cascading",
          "name": "1.css",
          "type": "folder"
        },
        {
          "dir": "folder/cascading",
          "name": "2.css",
          "type": "folder"
        },
        {
          "dir": "folder/cascading",
          "name": "3.css",
          "type": "folder"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For the moment I can just display every object and the deepth of it (with  console.log("-".repeat(count) + "element: " + child.tagName); ) in my console

Comment: DOM objects already are Javascript objects.  It's not clear at all what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Actually, I need to convert my HTML code into objects with specific properties which one is called "children" and contains the children of the objects. Concretely I need to convert all the "li" and "ul" into JSON for a better visibility and because my teacher would that.

Comment: A DOM node containing children has nothing to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a structure for your problem
I think should work

```
function Node(dirName,name,type){
  this.dir=dirName;
  this.name=name;
  this.type=type;
}
function parentNode(dirName,name,type,childArray){
  Node.call(this,dirName,name,type);
  this.children=childArray;
}
parentNode.prototype=Object.create(Node.prototype);

var node1=new Node("folder/cascading","1.css","folder");
var node2=new Node("folder/cascading","2.css","folder");
var childArray=[];
childArray.push(node1);

childArray.push(node2);
var parentNode1=new Node("folder","cascading","folder",childArray);
```

I guess this structure works for nested level's of ul and li's
Here Node is common for parent and children.
A parent node will have child nodes as an extra property

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can extract an idea thanks to your code ;)

Comment: If it helped you in anyway..consider accepting the answer